EJB - Inject into @Schedule @Singleton with @Produces fails; no scheduler running
I want to call this method regularly to clean up Apache HTTP connection pool in an EJB context. For that I created this scheduler class:
@DependsOn("PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager")
public class IdleConnectionMonitor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdleConnectionMonitor.class);
    @Inject
    private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

    public IdleConnectionMonitor(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager) {
        this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
    }

    @Schedule(second = "30")
    public void cleanUpPool() {
        LOGGER.debug("PoolStats counters meaning: max: total connections count; free: available to be reused/free/idle; leased: currently executing requests; waiting: the requests being blocked awaiting a free connection");
        tracePoolStats("HTTP client pool stats in the beginning: ");
        tracePoolStats("HTTP client pool stats before recycling:");
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tracePoolStats("HTTP client pool stats after recycling:");
    }
    private void tracePoolStats(String messagePrefix) {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            PoolStats poolStats = poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getTotalStats();
            LOGGER.debug(messagePrefix + "(max/free/leased/waiting): {} | {} | {} | {}",
                    poolStats.getMax(), poolStats.getAvailable(), poolStats.getLeased(), poolStats.getPending());
        }
    }
}

But it's not launching. I cannot find logs.
If I put @Singleton on it, JBoss EAP tells me it has to have a default constructor, but for me, it depends on the connection manager, lacking which it would not work of course. So I cannot define it as @Stateless or @Singleton.
What else should I do to make it work?
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager comes from another Producer class which @Produces the instance.
public class RestServiceProducer {

    @Produces
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
        if (poolingHttpClientConnectionManager == null) {
            this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultSocketConfig(
                    SocketConfig.copy(SocketConfig.DEFAULT)
                            .setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS)
                            .build()
            );
        }
        return poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
    }
}

It's lazily creating the instance when first request is launched. I could add @StartUp without problem, though.

At last I find it's possible to @Inject the PoolingConnectionManager just as usual, and I need to define this class as @Startup @Singleton. The PoolingConnectionManager can come from a @Produces method.
@Singleton
@Startup
public class IdleConnectionMonitor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdleConnectionMonitor.class);

    @Inject
    private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

    @Schedule(second = "*/30", minute = "*", persistent = false, hour = "*")
    public void cleanUpPool() {
        LOGGER.debug("PoolStats counters meaning: max: total connections count; free: available to be reused/free/idle; leased: currently executing requests; waiting: the requests being blocked awaiting a free connection");
        tracePoolStats("Job Manager HTTP client pool stats in the beginning: ", poolingHttpClientConnectionManager);
        tracePoolStats("Job Manager HTTP client pool stats before recycling:", poolingHttpClientConnectionManager);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tracePoolStats("Job Manager HTTP client pool stats after recycling:", poolingHttpClientConnectionManager);
    }

    private void tracePoolStats(String messagePrefix, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager) {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            PoolStats poolStats = poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getTotalStats();
            LOGGER.debug(messagePrefix + "(max/free/leased/waiting): {} | {} | {} | {}",
                    poolStats.getMax(), poolStats.getAvailable(), poolStats.getLeased(), poolStats.getPending());
        }
    }
}

And producer:
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@ApplicationScoped
public class RestServiceProducer {
    ...
    @Produces
    @Lock(WRITE)
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
        if (this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager == null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Creating new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager");
            this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
            poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultSocketConfig(
                    SocketConfig.copy(SocketConfig.DEFAULT)
                            .setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS)
                            .build()
            );
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Returning old PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager");
        }
        return poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
    }
}

